# How do i fix 'Error:Opening the cache...' or 'The package list or status file could not be parsed'?

Tags: apt, package-management, 16.04, dependencies

This error message was shown:

```
Error: Opening the cache(E:Could not open file/var/lib/apt/lists/
in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-i386_Packages-open(13:Permission denied),E:Problem opening /var/lib/apt/lists/
in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-i386_Packages,E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.)
```

How can i fix this error?

Comment: When do you see this error? Open "Software & Updates" from the dash, and tell me what your server is set to now. Change it to something else and see if the error goes away.

Comment: @heynnema, this error is shown as a notification in my top panel.

Comment: @heynema, under which option can we find where the server is set to in "Software & Updates"?

Comment: Did you even look? It's in the first tab when you open S&U.

Comment: yeah I did look in the ubuntu software tab....well did you mean the 'download from' dropdown list?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for. Whilst you're at it, start Synaptic from the Dash, click on the RELOAD button, then copy/paste the results here.

Comment: @heynnema, I did what you had initially told me to do i.e. to change the sever and after downloading and installing updates,this problem got corrected.Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discussed, the problem is with your download server, found in "Software & Updates" tab 1. Change to another server and it'll work fine.

Answer (score 0):

What command did you do to get this output? Did you run this as `root`? See `man sudo`, `man whateverCommand`, and then do:

```
sudo whateverCommand
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, or solve the problem. Questions should be in "comments".